# Blockchain interoperability

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, sidechain, plasma, interoperability

i hope that you are doing well!
I wanna build an Blockchain interoperability approach based on side chain and i don't know how to start, so if someone can help me please don't hesitate to text me i really appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sidechains are Ethereum-compatible, independent blockchains which employ their own consensus models and block parameters to efficiently process transactions. The ability to move assets and data between chains is an important aspect of the sidechain environment. Applications use sidechains for fast & inexpensive transactions, but the results of these transactions should be easily transferrable cross-chain. This is sometimes referred to as a two-way peg. Since chains are independent of one another, resources are typically locked on one chain and minted(created) on another. When they are transferred back, they are burned(destroyed) and unlocked.

Token Bridge from POA Network is a very good reference implementation of the sidechain mode. You can find further details in their [GitHub repository].[1](https://github.com/poanetwork/tokenbridge)